# Json with json object nested Error: Cannot invoke "java.util.Iterator.hasNext()" because "<local8>" is null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a json file that has some parmeters with a nested object in it. And I'm trying to save this json file to the database. Altough I keep reciving this Exception:

" Cannot invoke "java.util.Iterator.hasNext()" because "" is null"

`

```
{
        "personId" : "1xxxxxxx",
        "invoiceDate" : "2020-10-12",
        "invoices":[
            {
            "invoiceAmount" :"300",
            "invoiceNumber" :"x123"
            },
        {
            "invoiceAmount" :"100",
            "invoiceNumber" :"x122"
        }
        ],   
}
```

`

So to insert an object in my DTO that has an array of (Invoices) I created an Object name invoices of type InvoicesDTO, then I tried to itirate through these Object everytime a request will be reviced using this API. But Still I get this error.

the dto's for Invoice and invoices:

```
`

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class InvoiceDTO {
  @NotNull(message = "PersonId can't be null")
  @PersonId
  private String personId;

  @NotNull(message = "invoiceDate can't be null")
  // @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"))
  @PastOrPresent
  @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
  private LocalDate invoiceDate;

  private InvoicesDTO invoices;
```

`

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class InvoicesDTO implements List<InvoicesDTO> {

    @NotNull(message = "invoice Number can't be null")
    private String invoiceNumber;

    @NotNull(message = "invoiceAmount can't be null")
    private Double invoiceAmount;
```

`

```
 try {
  //Add the new amount of the invoice to an existing debts
    Optional<Debts> debts = debtsRepository.findDebtsByPersonIdAndOrganization_id(invoiceDTO.getPersonId(),organization.get().getId());
    Optional<Madeen> madeenOptional = madeenRepository.findByPersonId(invoiceDTO.getPersonId());

  List<InvoicesDTO> invoicesDTO = invoiceDTO.getInvoices();

  for (InvoicesDTO invoices : invoicesDTO) {  //The error is here
      Debts newDebt = new Debts(); //Only debts
      newDebt.setPersonId(invoiceDTO.getPersonId());
      newDebt.setCreatedDate(LocalDate.now());
      newDebt.setUpdatedDate(invoiceDTO.getInvoiceDate());
      newDebt.setDebtAmount(invoices.getInvoiceAmount());
      newDebt.setInvoiceNumber(invoices.getInvoiceNumber());
      newDebt.setOrganization(organization.get());
      debtsRepository.save(newDebt);
    }
```

`

Comment: A unique query expects one and only one result. Your query returned two results. There is your error.

Comment: Why on earth are you implementing `List`? Instead just create a `List<InvoicesDTO>` and remove the `implements` list.

Comment: @M.Deinum I didn't understand you suggestion. elaborate more please!

Comment: I don't see why you are implementing `List`, seems like a basic misunderstanding of java.